# Size validation max value is {javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have  a field in the student class in the Spring MVC

```
@Size(min=5,max=30)
    private String studentHobby;
```

I have put the size validation for it.

and write the following code in the spring-servlet.xml file

```
 </bean>
<bean id="messageSource" class= "org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename"  value="/WEB-INF/studentmessages"/>
</bean>
```

studentmessages.properties files is:

```
Size.student1.studentHobby =pls enter a  value for {0} between {2} and {1} characters
```

I am getting the value of min field but not getting for max field

> pls enter a value for studentHobby between 5 and {javax.validation.constraints.Size.message} characters

can someone let me know what could be the reason for not getting the max value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how but when i changed the

**studentmessages.properties files as:**

```
Size.student1.studentHobby = pls enter a  value for {0} between {2} and {4} characters.
```

It gives me the right message as

```
pls enter a value for studentHobby between 5 and 30 characters.
```